# Using a SQL join to combine data rows from 4 tables without repeating row id's as depicted in the desired results table shown below

Tags: sql, pivot, outer-join

Table A

[image]

Table B

[image]

Table C

[image]

Table D

[image]

Desired results

[image]

Thank you in advance for any assistance provided to achieve the desired results in this case. My goal is to stitch multiple tables together in this manner assuming my database is not able to support the use os a FULL JOIN Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate a `full join` with `union all` and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    id, 
    coalesce(max(case when idx = 1 then col end), '0') col1,
    coalesce(max(case when idx = 2 then col end), '0') col2,
    coalesce(max(case when idx = 3 then col end), '0') col3,
    coalesce(max(case when idx = 4 then col end), '0') col4
from (
    select id, 1 idx, col1 col from table1
    union all select id, 2, col2 from table2
    union all select id, 3, col3 from table3
    union all select id, 4, col4 from table4
) t
group by id
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` to get 1 result set that has all 4 combined.

Then from that you can group by the `ID`.
And use conditional aggregation to pivot the COL values on the table sources.

```
SELECT ID
, MAX(CASE WHEN Src = 1 THEN Col ELSE '0' END) AS COL1
, MAX(CASE WHEN Src = 2 THEN Col ELSE '0' END) AS COL2
, MAX(CASE WHEN Src = 3 THEN Col ELSE '0' END) AS COL3
, MAX(CASE WHEN Src = 4 THEN Col ELSE '0' END) AS COL4
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, 1 AS Src, COL1 AS Col
    FROM TableA

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ID, 2, COL2
    FROM TableB

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ID, 3, COL3
    FROM TableC

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ID, 4, COL4
    FROM TableD
) q
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

`UNION ALL` the tables, put each column in right position. `GROUP BY` the result.

```
select id, max(col1), max(col2), max(col3), max(col4)
from
(
    select id, col1, null as col2, null as col3, null as col4 from tableA
    union all
    select id, null, col2, null, null from tableB
    union all
    select id, null, null, col3, null from tableC
    union all
    select id, null, null, null, col4 from tableD
) dt
group by id
```

If you need '0' in the result instead of the null values, use `COALESCE()`

```
select id, coalesce(max(col1),'0'), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.

```
Select 
coalesce(Col1, '0') as Col1,
coalesce(Col2, '0') as Col2,
coalesce(Col3, '0') as Col3,
coalesce(Col4, '0') as Col4
(

select ID from TableA union
select ID from TableB union
select ID from TableC union
select ID from TableD 

) TbLID
left join TableA on TableA.ID =  TbLID.ID
left join TableB on TableB.ID =  TbLID.ID
left join TableC on TableC.ID =  TbLID.ID
left join TableD on TableD.ID =  TbLID.ID
```

Comment: Hint: `coalesce(Col1, '0')`.

Comment: BTW, no need to do SELECT DISTINCT combined with UNION, since UNION removes all duplicates.

Comment: Thanks @jarlh, makes it better